# Kafka Cluster : Why should we use several broker hostname for a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm working on Kafka cluster installation but I've seen that some people use several broker hostname to connect to the kafka cluster. Why should we use several broker hostname for a cluster ? Why don't we use a cluster hostname ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A cluster doesn't have a hostname

Clients use multiple (or all) broker addresses as the bootstrap connection for fault tolerance

Comment: Thanks so we could use one broker adress for connection, right ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer says use more than one